# Acquiring Project North angle

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way of programmatically acquiring the true north angle through View API or something similiar?
Current approach is approximating the angle with photoshop. I am looking for a way to automatically get the north angle from the model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about Revit models with **True North** different from **Project North**.

A model is translated to Viewer using project coordinates, i.e. using Project North.

**EDIT**

Maybe that's what you need:

`viewer.model.getData().metadata["custom values"].angleToTrueNorth`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! So there is no reference to the projects orientation towards the north pole which I can get?

Comment: Checking if the above edit helped, if that, remember to accept as solution :)